# How to display filelist in collapse state using os module

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, frontend, streamlit

I am trying to display file list in collapse state and couldn't find a solution. After running the app, it always display in opened file list which is messy in user's eye.
if you guys have any idea on how to achieve it, would help :)

code i am using:

```
import os
import streamlit as st

st.write(' 1 docx-raw')
filelist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/lungsang/Desktop/levelpack-UI/content/A0/1 docx-raw"):
    for file in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, file)
        filelist.append(filename)
st.write(filelist)
```

How it displays :
[image: how it displays currently]

Desired displays in collapse state:

[image: collapse state]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `st.expander()` to accomplish that task.

```py
filelist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/lungsang/Desktop/levelpack-UI/content/A0/1 docx-raw"):
    for file in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, file)
        filelist.append(filename)
with st.expander(" 1 docx-raw"):
    st.write(filelist)
```